# Amazon signature does not match using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've generated the signature using javascript. but it shows Signature does not match always.

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>  
 <script>
   var service = "AWSECommerceService";
   var timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
   var operation = "ItemSearch";
   var secret = "MYSECRETKEY";
   var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(service + operation + timestamp, secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
   console.log('http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=mykey&AssociateTag=mytag-20&Keywords=harry%20potter&Operation='+operation+'&SearchIndex=Books&Service='+service+'&Timestamp='+timestamp+'&Version=2018-06-01&Signature='+signature);
 </script>
```

Comment: give any suggestion please. is this way is correct or not?

Comment: you should be doing this server-side using node or whatever server side language you want. If you have your secret in the client anyone can get to it using the debugger tools in the browser.